# How do I specify the proper type to return in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a method that returns a list of a certain type

```
  fun update(
    financialMethods: List<FinancialMethods>
  ): CompletableFuture<List<ApvFinancialMethods>> {
    return post<List<ApvFinancialMethods>>(
      "/apv-financial-methods",
      financialMethods,
      List::class.java
    )
  }
```

The lib being used is just a wrapper over `restTemplate` .

```
  protected <T> CompletableFuture<T> post(String path, Object obj, Class<T> clazz, Object... uriVariables) {
    return post(path, obj, clazz, new RequestParams(), uriVariables);
  }


  protected <T> CompletableFuture<T> post(String path, Object obj, Class<T> clazz, RequestParams requestParams, Object... uriVariables) {

    String paramString = getParamString(requestParams, true, true);

    T t = cubsWsRestTemplate.exchange(path + paramString, HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(obj, headers), clazz, uriVariables).getBody();

    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(t);
  }
```

But I have a problem with my `List::class.java`.  The error I am getting is `Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch`.  If I change all of my lists to `List<*>`, then it works, but the type I get out is obviously not what I want.  What do I change `List::class.java` to to make my method work?

Comment: That case what type you are getting?

Comment: Which REST library are you using?

Comment: what is the signature of `post`?

Comment: `Type erasure` is the case

Comment: Is it a compile error or a runtime one?

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the generic type from `post<List<ApvFinancialMethods>>`. I've found that the intellij converter erroneously adds these in a lot of places where the type can be inferred by the compiler. This should be redundant in this case and clearly kotlin's `List` does not match the java one.